# Java WebService: usage of existing class instead of generated

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jdeveloper

here is what i wanna do. I've got 3 Java projects. Project A provides a WebService. Project B consumes this WebService. Project C is a shared library for both projects, which contains a class XRef.

The WebService in A returns an objects of Type XRef. B consumes this WebService and uses also XRef from C. When I create a WebService Proxy, it also produces another XRef class.

Is there a way that it uses the existing XRef class instead of creating another one?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to merge the projects and have different packaging scripts for each one.

Another solution would be to package all JAXB(I suppose) generated classes into a jar and use it in all 3 projects.

JAXB has some nice Ant tasks u can use for that and the same goes for JAX-WS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I found another solution. JAXB offers a way to customize bindings. But I'm not sure.